# Build Kotlin Android App in AOSP 13 source code

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, frameworks, android-source

- I'm trying to build Kotlin android app in AOSP 13 source code.
- I have added all the dependency in Android.bp file, mentioned in
  build.gradle file by downloading .jar and .aar files from
  https://mvnrepository.com/
- getting error of importing files while building apps.
- **Getting below errors**

> error: supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please
> make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
>
> class com.trello.rxlifecycle.components.support.RxAppCompatActivity,
> unresolved supertypes: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
>
> class okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor, unresolved supertypes:
> okhttp3.Interceptor

```
error: unresolved reference: DOWNLOAD_SERVICE
        val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(RxAppCompatActivity.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager

error: unresolved reference: synthetic
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.buttonDownloadFile

error: unresolved reference: rx
import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers

error: cannot access 'android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity' which is
 a supertype of 'com.myapp.sample.MainActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
class MainActivity : RxAppCompatActivity() {

error: unresolved reference: setContentView
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Android.bp

```
package {
    // See: http://go/android-license-faq
    default_applicable_licenses: ["Android-Apache-2.0"],
}
android_app {
    name: "myapp",
    srcs: ["app/src/main/java/**/*.kt", "app/src/main/java/**/*.java"],
    resource_dirs: ["app/src/main/res"],
    manifest: "app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
    sdk_version: "system_current",
    target_sdk_version: "33",
    min_sdk_version: "30",
    static_libs: [
    "java-libs",
    "androidx.appcompat_appcompat",
        "android-support-v7-appcompat",
        "com.google.android.material_material",
        "androidx-constraintlayout_constraintlayout",
        "androidx.core_core",
        "androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-runtime",
        "androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview",
    "androidx.work_work-runtime",
        "rxlifecycle-0.6.1.aar",
        "rxlifecycle-components-0.6.1.aar",
    "com.google.android.material_material",
        "androidx.preference_preference",
        "androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-extensions",
    "core-ktx-1.6.0.aar",
            "kotlinx-coroutines-android",
        "kotlinx-coroutines-core",
    "guava",
    "filelogger-1.0.7.aar",
    ],

    asset_dirs: [
        "app/src/main/assets/",
    ],

    kotlincflags: ["-Xjvm-default=enable"],
    optimize: {
     proguard_flags_files: [
          "app/proguard-rules.pro",
          "proguard.flags",
     ],
    },
    privileged: true,
    certificate: "platform",
}
java_import {
    name: "java-libs",
    jars: [
        "libs/adapter-rxjava-2.4.0.jar",
        "libs/gson-2.10.1.jar",
        "libs/guava-30.1.1-android.jar",
        "libs/kotlin-stdlib-1.5.20.jar",
        "libs/okhttp-3.11.0.jar",
                 "libs/converter-gson-2.4.0.jar",
        "libs/logging-interceptor-3.11.0.jar",
        "libs/retrofit-2.4.0.jar",
        "libs/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime-1.6.0.jar",
        "libs/rxjava-1.1.7.jar",
        "libs/jsr305-3.0.2.jar",
        "libs/error_prone_annotations-2.21.1.jar",
        "libs/okio-1.14.0.jar",
    ],
    sdk_version: "33"
}
android_library_import {
     name: "rxlifecycle-0.6.1.aar",
     aars: ["libs/rxlifecycle-0.6.1.aar"],
     sdk_version: "33"
}
android_library_import {
     name: "rxlifecycle-components-0.6.1.aar",
     aars: ["libs/rxlifecycle-components-0.6.1.aar"],
     sdk_version: "33"
}
android_library_import {
     name: "core-ktx-1.6.0.aar",
     aars: ["libs/core-ktx-1.6.0.aar"],
     sdk_version: "33"
}
android_library_import {
     name: "filelogger-1.0.7.aar",
     aars: ["libs/filelogger-1.0.7.aar"],
     sdk_version: "33"
}
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0-beta02'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$rootProject.recyclerview"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.googleMaterial"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0"

    // Network
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$rootProject.interceptorRetrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"

    // Parser
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.retrofitVersion"

    //rxlifecycle
    implementation "com.trello:rxlifecycle:$rootProject.rxlifecycleVersion"
    implementation "com.trello:rxlifecycle-components:$rootProject.rxlifecycleVersion"
    //rxlifecycle

    // Reactive
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rootProject.rxjava2Version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.rxandroidVersion"
    // Reactive
    //log
    implementation 'com.github.bosphere.android-filelogger:filelogger:1.0.7'
    //log

    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-android")


}
```

}

Comment: Could you share your Android.bp?

Comment: @ÁlisonVenâncio thanks for response, I have edited my question with adding Android.bp and dependencies from build.gradle, basically I have added all the libraries which is mentioned in build.gradle file.